# Correct method to save and replay a sequence of events

Tags: database, data-structures, data-modeling

we're building a mobile software with React Native where a user can start/build a session of some actions that should be recorded and replayed later. Those actions include playing some videos, seeking a played video, pausing and playing again, showing custom messages for a specific period of time... etc.

The best model we made so far is this:

```
 {
  "episode": {
    "name": "The New MacBook Pro",
    "events": {
      "1589168577": {
        "source": "stream",
        "action": "play"
        "link": "https://example.com/s1/ep1.mp3"
      },
      "1589168665-1589168223": {
        "source": "video",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoQOmOlWLZo",
        "action": "play"
      },
      "1589169026-1589169827": {
        "source": "video",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoQOmOlWLZo",
        "action": "pause"
      },
      "1589169381-1589169237": {
        "source": "video",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoQOmOlWLZo",
        "action": "play"
      },
      "1589169420-1589169124": {
        "source": "video",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoQOmOlWLZo",
        "action": "seek",
        "seek": "399"
      },
      "1589169540-1589169235": {
        "source": "video",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoQOmOlWLZo",
        "action": "stop"
      },
      "1589169523-1589169235": {
        "source": "message",
        "text": "Keep following up for the discound code",
        "action": "show"
      },
      "1589169542": {
        "source": "stream",
        "action": "stop"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On Firebase, we recorde the actions we need ro be replayed (as above), when a user plays the session, all the events must be played in the exact sequence. The `events` node keys hold the timestamps of starting and ending of the event, separated by a dash. (PS. timestamps above are wrong, and put there just as examples);

[image]

The app starts playing the session and compares the current timestamp with the saved ones in `events` node, if they are equal, the action is played.

Now, the problem is when a user replaying a session, seeked to specific location on the timeline where an action is already being played, we had issues with this, some events are being missed.

I am sure there are better ways to do this but I can't come up with a better way to save the data in a correct way that helps us replay those actions correctly.

A good example of what we're doing is a video being played on Youtube where a user seeks to a spefic time that an AD should appear, and a subscription button appears at another location, subtitles..... etc.

I appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: I'm not the best person to answer this myself, but can you show us where you're having a problem and what the exact issue is?  For example, even if you can't really show us the code, can you give us a basic description of the logic and the specific step where it's failing, along with any error messages or symptoms?

Comment: For example, host starts to play a video at 10:00 and at 10:03 and seeks the video for few minutes. If you play this recorded session you can't detect the video seek event if you seek the session directly to > 10:04.

Comment: Why not to store the exact actions (what he or she does),  but what events are triggered  (luckily most devices are one-app at a time):
at 9:59 opened video
at 10:00 pushed play button
at 10:03 clicked seek to a time 15:45
at 10:05 clicked pause
at 10:15 clicked resume
at 10:30 closed the video
at 10:35 session closed

This will allow you to track what user performed,  and as such keeping a history of actions you can replay what exactly is on the user's screen (similar to what redux dev tools does), or anything needed.